# Why is canvas max memory only reached when doing a drawing operation

Tags: javascript, ios, memory, html5-canvas

On iOS the max allocated memory for canvases is `memSize()/4` which often resolve to 256mb

Now consider this code:

```
const createImage = () => {
  const size = 512

  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
  canvas.height = size
  canvas.width = size
  document.body.appendChild(canvas)
}

const createImages = nbImage => {
  let count = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < nbImage; i++) {
    try {
      createImage()
      count = count + 1
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(i, e)
      break
    }
  }
  console.log(`done for ${count} MB`)
  console.log(`there are ${nbImage - count} remaining canvas to create...`)
}

createImages(500)
```

Running this on my iPhone 8 outputs:

```
done for 500 MB
there are 0 remaining canvas to create...
```

When you change createImage to this:

```
const createImage = () => {
  const size = 512

  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
  canvas.height = size
  canvas.width = size
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red'
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, size, size)
}
```

you get an output like this one:

```
Total canvas memory use exceeds the maximum limit (256mb).
256 - TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'ctx.fillStyle = 'red'')
done for 256 MB
there are 244 remaining canvas to create...
```

Notice that I event removed the appendChild in the second version of createImage

I event tried to call the createImages function again after like 60seconds if there is any remaining canvases to be created like this:

```
if (count < nbImage) setTimeout(createImages, 60000, nbImage - count)
```

to see if the GC would have time to collect in the meantime, but to no avail.

I know that if I change my createImage to this:

```
const createImage = () => {
  const size = 512

  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
  canvas.height = size
  canvas.width = size
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red'
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, size, size)
  canvas.height = 0
  canvas.width = 0
}
```

The 500 canvases get created, but the problem is I ultimately want to append my canvases to the dom and resetting their width and height to 0 isn't really possible in that case.

Any insight?

Answer (score 0):

Why would they allocate any memory for the bitmap when they don't know yet how much memory they'll actually need or even if they'll have to allocate any?

Before you initialise the context, the canvas holds no bitmap buffer, just like any element.

The context can be either a webgl context (2 bitmap buffers would need to be allocated), a 2d context (1 buffer) or an ImageBitmapRenderer (no bitmap buffer).

So your observation makes perfect sense.

Comment: That is what I figured out. So if I understand correctly canvas' buffer are always in JS memory stack if they are only referenced in the dom?

Comment: @MaloGuertin I'm not sure to get your comment... The HTMLCanvasElement object in itself weights almost nothing in memory. What will use memory though is the pixel buffer(s) of the rendering context. That their canvas is in the active document or not will have no incidence though.